# Updating author information on annotated/signed tags in git using filter-branch or a similar tool

Tags: git

Is there a good way to update the author email and name of annotated or signed tags for an entire git repository?  For commits, I use git filter-branch with the following script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "you@example.com" ];
then
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="My Name";
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="addy@example.com";
    git commit-tree "$@";
else
    git commit-tree "$@";
fi
```

and command

```bash
git filter-branch -f \
--tag-name-filter cat \
--commit-filter '/some/path/update_email.sh $@' master
```

Now, with the `--tag-name-filter cat` flag, all of the tags are updated to the new commits, but they contain old author information.  I'd like an automated way to update this contact information as well.  More specifically, I know that `--tag-name-filter` strips GPG signatures.  If there's a way to update the signatures as well, that would be ideal.  In this case, assume that I possess the GPG key of the signatures being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your commands seems to be similar to [this blog post](http://xrunhprof.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/changing-git-committers-and-authors-with-python/), which mentioned:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '/path/to/authors.py "$@"' \
  --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But, once that filter is done, it also remove the original references:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ \ 
  | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

Maybe that is the missing step in your case.

See also if a tool like [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) couldn't take care of both steps in one command.